# Extracting filter coefficients from a transfer function

Tags: signal-processing, control-systems

What is the correct way to extract coefficients (in a form I could use in `RecurrenceFilter`) from a filter which I have represented as a Mathematica transfer function object, ie. something of the form `TransferFunctionModel[...]`? I can easily extract the various parts of this object using array indices, but surely there is an "official" method?

I looked at the Mathematica documentation. But, for example, the coefficients used in `In[101]` [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DigitalFilterDesign.html) look like they've been copied manually from `In[92]`, rather than obtained through a coefficient extraction function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first question would be why not use RecurrenceFilter[TransferFunctionModel[...],...].

There is more than one way to get the coefficients. The following will work for rational, scalar systems, without delays - which is what is handled by `RecurrenceFilter`.

```
tfd1 = TransferFunctionExpand[tfd][s][[1, 1]]

Reverse@CoefficientList[#, s] & /@ Through@{Denominator, Numerator}@tfd1
```

> {{21, -25, 15, -3}, {1, 3, 3, 1}}

Comment: In answer to your question: I want to use Mathematica to derive my filter so I can use it somewhere else. Your solution is the same as mine but it didn't seem right to just unpack the internals of Mathematica's structure.